# Where does Git save user's secret tokens by default?

Tags: git

I removed my .gitconfig by accident. I added new identies by

```
git add [file]
git remote ... [identity addition]
```

I am surprised when Git did not make a .gitconfig file which contain my secret tokens to my Home.

Git must have put the secret tokens elsewhere. However, I have not been able to find the location.

The reason for that the data is not at .gitconfig may that I have .gitconfig at my .gitignore -file.

**Where does Git save the user's secret tokens** for github when they are not at Home's .gitconfig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub uses SSH authentication so your tokens will be stored wherever your SSH client stores them. On Linux it would be under ~/.ssh.

---

I think you might mean where does git store the configuration information about your remotes?  Usually it's not in your ~/.gitconfig.  Usually it's in the "config" file under the ".git" directory in the root of your project.

Comment: @Talljoe: I had some tokens at my .gitconfig for github before the file removal accident. --- Are these tokens same as what SSH client stares?

Comment: I opened the following question because I want to know the exact details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081194/how-does-git-decide-where-to-save-secret-tokens-exactly

Answer (score -1):

You have to add your GitHub tokens yourself. The instructions are on GitHub