# How does Git decide where to save secret tokens exactly?

Tags: git

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060817/where-does-git-save-users-secret-tokens-by-default).

I am interested in how Git decides where to save secret tokens exactly when you run

```
git remote add github...
```

In other words, I would like to know which file affects this behavior. I know that it can be changed, since that info was stored to my old .gitconfig, while it is now at .git/.

This may be a recent change in Git.

**Which file does make Git to save secret tokens to /.git/?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git remote add github git@github.com:username/Project.git
```

The above command creates an entry in `.git/config` file. For example:

```
[remote "github"]
        url = git@github.com:username/Project.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

Comment: @Alan: It seems that this is the only place where Git saves the secret data.

Comment: @Masi: Git makes many entries in `.git/config` as part of some commands.

Comment: 1.) "git remote add ..." doesn't add any 'secret token' 2.) repository configuration file (.git/config) is the only sane place to add remotes configuration, which are repository-specific